# How to join between two tables to find which row has a maximum value

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

> Tables: CRIMES, SUSPECTS
>
> Who of the suspects have got the longest prison term?
>
> In the resulting table show name, date in years, months and days. Use a variable to make the expressions you use shorter in the query and also in the subquery.
>
> TABLE CRIMES:
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> TABLE SUSPECT:
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> so on....

I couldn't find the longest prison term.

I tried to find start_date and end_date of prison:

> select crime_id, end_date-start_date as Prison_date from crimes ;

then tried to write it in years, month and date

> select crime_id,
> TRUNC(months_between(end_date,start_date)/12) years,
> TRUNC(months_between(end_date,start_date)  -
> (TRUNC(months_between(end_date,start_date)/12)*12)) months,
> TRUNC((months_between(end_date,start_date) -
> TRUNC(months_between(end_date,start_date)))*30) days
> from crimes;

and join with suspect:

> select name, (select end_date-start_date as Prison_date from crimes)
> from suspect natural join crimes;

However it is failed, how can I find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables on `suspect_id` (not `crime_id`) and get the difference between the start and end of the sentence and then sort the table in descending order of sentence length and fetch the first row with ties to find the maximums:

```sql
SELECT s.name,
       FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date) / 12) AS years,
       FLOOR(MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date), 12)) AS months,
       31 * MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date), 1) AS days
FROM   crime c
       INNER JOIN suspects s
       ON c.suspect_id = s.suspect_id
ORDER BY
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

If you are using Oracle 11 or earlier, then you can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT s.name,
         FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date) / 12) AS years,
         FLOOR(MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date), 12)) AS months,
         31 * MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date), 1) AS days,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MONTHS_BETWEEN(c.end_date, c.start_date) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   crime c
         INNER JOIN suspects s
         ON c.suspect_id = s.suspect_id
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```